# Why must named functions be in a separate file in hugs?

Tags: haskell, hugs

In [Haskell in 5 steps](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_in_5_steps) the factorial function is defined as follows:

```
let fac n = if n == 0 then 1 else n * fac (n-1)
```

But for hugs, it says that fac needs to be in fac.h. Can anyone explain why this is the case - missing the ability to define named functions seems like a massive limitation for an interpreter?

Comment: Just FYI, GHCi can define functions. I don't see much reason to be using Hugs these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic answer as far as I can tell is that the Hugs interactive toplevel is essentially an expression parser, and function/data definitions are not expressions. Your example actually would work if you made it an expression and wrote `let fac n = if n == 0 then 1 else n * fac (n-1) in fac 19`. Adding support for this would be a pretty big effort, and apparently the Hugs implementors thought that it was good enough to require function/data definitions to be in files.

Answer (score 2):

Hugs misses the ability to define any named functions (recursive or not). It also misses the ability to define data types.

Comment: This says that it has the limitation, not why the limitation exists.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but I'm still curious why they decided not to provide this feature.